# returning no methods after calling a class

Tags: php, class

I want to do this. I have an instance of my class and after I want to return without using the method. How can I do this?

I want to do;

```
<?php 

class a {

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function get(){
        return 'hello world';
    }

}

echo (new a());  // print hello world

?>
```

Comment: You can't echo an object instance unless it implements `__toString`. Is that what you mean? It's not very clear.

Comment: `$test = new a;
echo $test -> get();`.

Comment: Or `echo (new a) -> get();`.

Comment: Its unclear what yo are trying to do but you can try either `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Comment: @RobertRocha From the code it looks like to OP need to use the [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method, which allows you to define the string representation of the class

Comment: Bu laravel yapılandırmasını nasıl yaparım config('database.host'); normalde yapılandır config('database.host') -> get (); yapılması gerekiyor.